# @protocol on IOS parsing data 2 way?

Tags: iphone, protocols, modal-dialog

I have login Code like this :

```
@protocol LoginDelegate 

-(void)DUsername:(NSString *) username DPassword:(NSString *) password;

@end


@interface loginipad : UIViewController {
    id<LoginDelegate> delegate;
    IBOutlet UITextField *edusername;
    IBOutlet UITextField *edpassword;
}
```

and then i use this object on mainViewController like this :

```
@interface mainViewController : UIViewController<LoginDelegate> {
```

and call this methode on mainViewController

```
-(void)DUsername:(NSString *) username DPassword:(NSString *) password{
    userlogin=[username retain];
    passlogin=[password retain];
    if (!scm.isRunning) {
        [scm connectToHost:@"localhost" onPort:8080];
    }    
}
```

This method is success to parsing data from login modalview to mainViewController, but i want show progress of process or any message from mainViewController to login modal view when login button is klick (i try MBPrgoressHUD but no success due i use this login on modal view).
My Question how i can parsing data from mainViewController to This login modalview ?
Thanks,
for call the method :

```
loginipad *plogin = [[loginipad alloc] initWithNibName:@"loginipad"  bundle:nil];
    plogin.delegate = self;
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:plogin];
    plogin.title=@"Login";


    [self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];


    [nc release];
    nc = nil;
    [plogin release];
    plogin = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

**answer completely edited**

Your question leads to multiple solutions and strategies.

#### First: general posibilities to implement  bidirectional data-transfer between two classes.

via multiple protocols: loose cupling but leads to import-loops which are annoying. I know ho to solve import loops for class-definitions (@class) but I dont know how to solve this for protocols

A.h:

```
#import "B.h"
@protocol ADelegate
-(void) adelegate:(NSString*)data;
@end
@interface A : NSObject<BDelegate>
{
    id<ADelegate> delegate;
}
@end
```

B.h:

```
#import "A.h"
@protocol BDelegate
-(void) bdelegate:(NSString*)data;
@end
@interface B : NSObject<ADelegate>
{
    id<BDelegate> delegate;
}
@end
```

via a single protocol: dense cupling :( but no import-loop (this is a working ugly style)

A.h:

```
//no import here needed
@protocol ADelegate
-(void) adelegate:(NSString*)data;
@end
@interface A : NSObject<BDelegate>
{
    id<ADelegate> delegate;
}
@end
```

B.h:

```
#import "A.h"
@interface B : NSObject<ADelegate>
{
    A* delegate;
}
@end
```

via pipe/stream: bidirectional data-transfer should by done using a pipe (unbuffered) or stream (buffered)
here I show you a small and simple delegate-pipe but there also exists a NSPipe/NSStream

DelegatePipe.h

```
@protocol DelegatePipeDelegate
- dataArrived:(NSString*)data;
@end

@interface DelegatePipe : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *delegates;
}
-(void)open:(id<DelegatePipeDelegate>)d;
-(void)close:(id<DelegatePipeDelegate>)d;
-(void)send:(NSString*)data;

@end
```

DelegatePipe.m

```
@implementation DelegatePipe

-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        delegates = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) dealloc
{
    [delegates release];
    delegates = nil;
}
-(void) open:(id <DelegatePipeDelegate>)d
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if([delegates containsObject:d])
            return;
        //if([delegates count]>=2) //Pipe contains originally only 2 delegates. but a broadcaster is also nice ;)
        //  return; 
        [delegates addObject:d];
    }
}
-(void) close:(id <DelegatePipeDelegate>)d
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        [delegates removeObject:d];
    }
}
-(void) send:(NSString *)data
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        for(id<DelegatePipeDelegate> d in delegates)
            [d dataArrived:data];
    }
}
@end
```

#### Second: KVO

KVO is often used in a ModelViewController (MVC) Pattern. eg: visualize data in a view. The network-connection-state in your case is part of data and your loginipad is a view (*and a controller*)

Authentificator.h

```
typedef enum eAuthState
{
    NOT_CONNECTED = 0,
    LOGIN_FAILED,
    CONNECING,
    CONNECTED
} AuthState;

@interface Authentificator : NSObject {
    AuthState state;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) AuthState state;
@end
```

Authentificator.m

```
...

-(void) doAuthWithUsername:(NSString*)name password:(NSString*)pw
{
    self.state = CONNECING;
    //do network-stuff
}

//delegate from network. here NSURLConnection
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //parse network-answer
    BOOL success = YES;

    if(success)
        self.state = CONNECTED;
    else
        self.state = LOGIN_FAILED;  
}
```

loginipad.h

```
@interface loginipad : UIViewController 
{
    Authentificator *auth;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Authentificator *auth;
@end
```

loginipad.m

```
@implementation loginipad
@synthesize auth;

//override setter for more comfortable use (add/removeObserver)
-(void) setAuth:(Authentificator *)a
{
    @synchronized(auth)
    {
        [auth removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"state"];
        [auth release];
        auth = a;
        [auth retain];
        [auth addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"state" options:0 context:nil];  
    }
}

-(IBAction) buttonClicked:(id)aSender
{
    self.auth = [Authentificator sharedAuthentificator];
}

-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if(![object isKindOfClass:Authentificator.class])
        return;
    AuthState state = ((Authentificator*)object).state;
    NSLog(@"curState: %i",state);
    //do sth with state
}

- (void)dealloc {
    self.auth = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Hi Thoomas, thanks for reply, i use this code for call loginipad from mainviewcontroller loginipad on my updated question.

Comment: so you create an instance, present it and release it. My naive approach would be to store the instance of loginipad: @interface MainViewController : UIViewController { loginipad *loginVC }. As a result you also have to send from loginipad back to MainViewController that the modal view is not longer visible if the user closes that view

Comment: hemm.., i'm not close the view for waiting data from mainView to modal view, i'm just parsing data to mainView and proccess it, by send user and password to server, if the user/password correct the modalview will be dismiss, this is work, but i want while the process authetication i want show message on modal view ex, loading, connected, auntentcated and successed..

Comment: may be the appropriate title is @protocol on IOS parsing data 2 way ? :).

Comment: Ok, you can do it like I described (store instance of loginipad and pass messages to that instance). You want to show connection-status-information. The current connection state is stored somewhere in another class oder in MainViewController. So I would easily make use of KVO (KeyValueObserving). Somewhere in your Data you have the state eg. in a singleton. you can register in your modalVC for this state and your loginipad-instance will get all changes of the state-variable which you can then present

Comment: check my edited answer for a KVO-sample. KVO is useful if you need an information in many classes. I think you are doing the login-stuff in the MainViewController. It is better to place the login and network-stuff in a new class.

Comment: thanks thomas, i have try your code but error like this 2011-05-22 20:29:15.063 simasnet[21905:207] -[mainViewController setPlogin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c4d7d0 on self.plogin = [[loginipad alloc] initWithNibName:@"loginipad"  bundle:nil]; which code make it error ?

Comment: maybe you forgot the @synthesize plogin

Comment: Sorry, i must add plogin to @synthesize, but the message not show, i give this code : if(self.plogin)
            [self.plogin StatusMessage:@"Connecting"]; "Connecting" not show on lable

Comment: this code on plogin -(void) StatusMessage:(NSString *) message{
    [edmessage setText:message];
    
}

Comment: use your debugger to check if the KVO-delegate is called. I've not testet my code, I just wrote it down here...

Comment: Hi thomas, sorry, i try use your KVO but i don't know how to use :), i just try your code until if(self.plogin)
    [self.plogin presentData:myData];
else
    ... present your data in MainVC, whe i debug the code no come to (self.plogin).

Comment: i've completely modified my answer